# I don't want that Del-button yanks the deleted character

Tags: vim

I don't want the 'Delete' button to yank the characters I delete.

I can give an example:

When cutting and pasting some rows to elsewhere.

```
code
code
code





code2
code2
code2
```

I want to cut `code` and paste it below `code2`. It is my habbit to first do `x` to the 3 lines of code and after that to delete the blank lines between `code` and `code2` with the `delete` button => when doing this my register changes to empty row.

Does anyone has a suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "black hole register":

```
"_d
```

To delete those blank lines, select them in *visual* mode and use the command above.

Comment: +1, I had no idea. For what I can tell by brief testing it's not "sticky"?

Comment: That does not work. I have to do "_d + arrow key to really delete... You know why?

Comment: @Ozkan, probably because you need `dd`. Being in hurry to illustrate the register, romainl probably forgot about the full delete command :)

Comment: `"_d` has been working perfectly for years. `"_` is the black hole register, `d` is the "delete" action, `"_d` is the key sequence you are supposed to hit to get rid of the selected text completely: "delete this thing into oblivion".

Comment: Another question: Can i bind `delete` and `backspace` buttons to this? so it only changes the blak hole register and not the register i am working on?

Comment: If there's a visual selection, `d` operates on it. If there's no visual selection, `d` waits for a motion to act on: `d2w` to delete 2 words to the right, `di(` to delete the content of `()`, etc. The same rules apply to `"_d` or `"ad` and friends: if there's no visual selection, it waits for a motion (`"_d$`, for example) but if there's a visual selection, `"_d` does exactly what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, you can do `nnoremap <Delete> "_d`, but I'd advise you to **not do that.** Learn to use Vim properly instead.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19815/discussion-between-ozkan-and-romainl)

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you cut or copy something in Vim, with `'x'` and `'y'` for instance, it's copied into a register. When you paste something, with `'p'`, you always paste the top element of the stack of registers (`""`).

To see all elements in the register stack type `:reg`

```
""   abc
"0   efg
"1   hij
```

A register starts with the `"` symbol. To paste register `"1` do: `"1p` (will copy `'hij'`).

Comment: As Michael Krelin commented you can also name registers before copying or deleting. As he suggest you can put the things you want to copy into "a and the other things in register "b. I didn't know about the 'black hole register', good to know.

Answer (score 2):

I believe, the only thing you can do is prefix your yank and put with, for instance `"a` and your delete with `"b`, so that they operate on different registers.

Comment: can you give an example of how using it with `y` and `p`?